# Грех и огрех

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Что такое грех - это понятно. А вот есть еще слово "огрех" - то есть, небольшая ошибка, недоработка.
Мне вот интересно, это два не связанных друг с другом слова, просто некогда образованных от общего корня, или "огрех" - это все-таки прямая производная от слова "грех"? Но второй вариант у меня вызывает некоторые сомнения: все-таки "грех" и "оплошность" - это несколько разные вещи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Грех - это изначально ошибка, промах (погрешить против истины), религиозное значение вторично (из ст.-сл. языка). Соответственно, грех - огрех, приставка О со значением "вокруг, рядом" (сравнить: звук - призвук).

Есть предположение, что о.-с. основа слова соотносится со значением "искривленный. скрученный". Родственное слово - грёзы (обман, мечта).

Comment: Действительно "огрех", как и погрешность, производное от "грех".

Answer (score 1):

Как и "огрех"в с/х - пропуск (плешина), или плохо обработанное место в поле при пахоте - тоже промах.Семёнов говорит,что др.-русск. слово ГРЕХ восходит к общеславянской основе grechъ, образованной из 
groi-s-us – «заблуждение», «путаница», «ошибка».В XI в. была известна и другая древнерусская форма этого слова – «съгр(ять)за» (ошибка, смешение), от «гр(ять)зь» – «грязь»(но не на почве, та писалась через юс, а не через ять).И грезить родственно не "греза"-мечта, а "греза"-диалектное "ошибка, путаница".Исконный смысл мы часто находим в диалектах.